# Custom comparator in Python

Tags: python, heap, comparator

I'm trying to write a custom comparator in Python, that compares two node objects based on the following rules
1. Least frequency
2. Shortest length
3. Lexicographic ordering.

Here's my node object

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key: str, value: int):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
```

This is my Comparator

```
class Comparator:
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.node = node

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.node.value > other.value:
            return True
        elif len(self.node.key) > len(other.key):
            return True
        elif self.node.key > other.key:
            return True
```

I'm trying to use this Comparator to push node items to a heap, this is my code,

```
frequency_map = Counter(string)
        for k, v in frequency_map.items():
            p = Node(k, v)
            heapq.heappush(self.heap, Comparator(p))
```

This throws up the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'Comparator' object has no attribute 'value'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you are trying to do here. Why do you have a separate Comparator class? Why don't you define `__lt__` directly on Node?

Comment: Oh I can try that. But wouldn't a comparator also do that essentially.

Comment: But the point is that your heap is now composed entirely of instances of Comparator, not of Node. So there is no point checking `other.value`.

Comment: Ok I could make it work by putting the __lt__ inside the node. Curious is there a way to do it with a comaprator too?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `Comparator` class:

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if self.node.value > other.value:
        return True
```

Both `self` and `other` are instances of `Comparator` (Python has no way of knowing this is just an object wrapper) and you need to check `other.node.value`.